# What can I return which is valid for every type of <T>?

Tags: templates, queue, c++17

I have a simple template function implementation for returning the front element from a queue.

```cpp
template<class T>
T Queue<T>::front(){  //Queue is a typical class implementation of queue
    if(head)          //head points to first element
        return head->data;   //head->data is of type T
    //else return -1  //I want to do something like this 
}
```

It returns first element if queue is not empty. I know that `front()` can work without returning anything in case of empty queue but I want to return something so that I can know if the queue is empty (and also to get rid of the compiler warning).

Question- What can I return when queue is empty? Since its return type is T so I can't return a predefined value(like bool or int) for all types of T.

Comment: Throw an exception?

Comment: Is this C++17? You can return `std::optional<T>`

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: you could return a default constructed `T`, but that doesn't really solve the problem and puts unnecessary restrictions on `T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can I return which is valid for every type of `<T>`?

One typical design, used in the C++ standard library is to return an iterator. This design is used for example in `find`.

Another design is to return a reference. This is used with `front` and `at` and subscript operator for example.

> Question- What can I return when queue is empty?

In the iterator design, it is typical to return an iterator to one past the last element.

In the reference case, you couldn't return anything because there is nothing to refer to. In this design, there are several alternatives, some used by the standard library in different contexts:

- Document a pre-condition for the function that it may not be called when the container is empty. If caller violates the pre-condition, then the behaviur of the program will be undefined. This is the approach that standard library uses with `front` and the subscript operator.
- Treat such case as an error. There are many ways to design error handling in C++, but a typical choice is throwing an exception. This is what the standard library does in the case of `at`.

---

Another design, not used so much in the standard library is to return a `std::optional<T>`, and to return `std::nullopt` in the empty case.

---

> I know that front() can work without returning anything

This is a potential misuderstanding. Instead of returning, you can for example throw. Or you can end the process. But letting the execution flow out of the function without `return` or `throw` will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hm... STL containers typically use `begin` and `end` for returning iterators while `front` and `back` indeed return elements or invoke UB if called on empty containers.

Comment: @Aconcagua The question is "What can I return which is valid for every type". What you return depends on context. The standard library uses many return types in different contexts.

Comment: Maybe just add the recommendation to rename the functions to meet the STL naming pattern if the iterators concept is adopted. That would avoid confusion at the users' side.

Comment: @Aconcagua I added examples where the standard library uses the different designs.

Comment: These are fine, but that wasn't my point (seems as if I need to learn to express myself more clearly...). `front` returning a reference is fine, same semantics as in STL. `front` returning iterators is quetionable, as STL uses `begin` for in that scenario. Thus I'd add a recommendation to – *if* using iterators – rather prefer the name `begin`, which would again conform to STL.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Return a pointer that's conditionally null.
- Throw an exception.
- Document that it's undefined behavior.

Depends on what conventions your project already has. Another thing is that you're returning the element by value, which is probably not the right call.

Comment: Can you explain why returning by value in this case is not right?

Comment: @avm The main reason is that people likely want to access the element itself, not a copy of it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. If someone wanted to modify the value at  front(), they may not be able to do so while front() is returning by value.